# Programmatically capture audio in OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-audio

I'm wondering how to listen into the audio stream produced by an app (say iTunes for example) in my application.  I am working for a client who needs this functionality in the app I'm working on (it's an audio analysis tool).   Preferably this would not involve using any kind of kernel extension to accomplish this.

I am not interested in hearing about "Audio HiJack" or any closed source solutions which do this.  Please remember I am trying to do this within a program I am writing.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.